# OS X App view managment in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, xib

I am trying to write my first own app for OS X with Swift (without any tutorial or anything) and this one will contain two different "pages". So I created another XIB file containing the first view and put it as Main interface. I created a little "Entry.swift" file containing the IBOutlets and variables of the first view, in which I wrote this:

```
@IBAction func validation(sender: AnyObject) //Right username and password needed to unlock the second view 
{
    if (usernameField.stringValue == "Stan" && passwordField.stringValue == "Test") || (usernameField.stringValue == "Nico" && passwordField.stringValue == "Test2")
    {
        accesLabel.textColor = NSColor.greenColor()
        accesLabel.stringValue = "Acces Granted"
        //GO TO THE OTHER XIB FILE (1)
    }
    else
    {
        accesLabel.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
        accesLabel.stringValue = "Acces Denied"
    }

}
```

But my questions are:

**Is this the best way to go from one window to another one ?**

and

**If yes, how can I code it ?** (1)

**If no, what is it ?**

I am new to iOS and OSX programming, since I learned in C# first... This was my first own programm in C# so I am trying to convert it.

Comment: I really hope you are not using this for anything remotely related to security. That plaintext is scary :-O

Comment: Nope, nothing serious. The main idea is creating a false program that would look like a FBI DataBase. Fun to run in public places...

Comment: Alright, just checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using only one storyboard but hidding/showing buttons regarding where you are ?  That might be a way for a light program...

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode6 you can now have Storyboards for OS X projects. In this case you can just create a segue from one window to another and trigger this segue programmatically whenever you want.

Comment: If you're just starting, there is no point in supporting legacy code, so you might as well learn on the latest technology stack.